# Can we create index for key/value of JSONB data type?

Tags: postgresql, index, postgresql-9.4, performance, postgresql-performance

Can we create an index for a key/value of a JSONB data type?

For example, for these schema:

```
CREATE TABLE x (
  id BIGSERIAL,
  data JSONB
);
CREATE TABLE y (
  id BIGSERIAL,
  data JSONB
);
```

The slow query:

```
SELECT *
FROM x
  LEFT JOIN y
    ON (y.data->>'x_id')::BIGINT = x.id
```

How to create an index for `y.data->>'x_id'` that can be used for that kind of query?

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html#JSON-INDEXING Also, please read https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Slow_Query_Questions about how to ask really meaningful questions about slow queries.

Comment: @dezso: I don't think the case is covered in the manual where you link to. That page discuses specific GIN index options for `jsonb`, but the OP just needs a plain btree index. I also think there is enough information in the question for this use case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest an [expression index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-expressional.html) on the value of the key 'x_id', cast to `bigint` - plain (default) **B-tree**, not GIN. One pitfall here: the short notation for type casts requires an additional set of parentheses to make the syntax work for index creation:

```
CREATE INDEX y_data_xid_idx ON y (((y.data->>'x_id')::bigint));
```

Alternatively,  use the explicit form (to the same effect):

```
CREATE INDEX y_data_xid_idx ON y (cast(y.data->>'x_id' AS bigint));
```

Comment: Is it possible to add such an index to a JSONB field with dynamic keys?