# PostgreSQL - CAST vs :: operator on LATERAL table function

Tags: postgresql, type-conversion, cast, operator

While I can

```
SELECT
  elem[1], elem[2]
FROM
  (
    VALUES ('1,2'::TEXT)
  ) AS q(arr),
  LATERAL CAST(String_To_Array(q.arr, ',') AS INT[]) AS elem
;
```

using an explicit call to `CAST`, I *can't*

```
SELECT
  elem[1], elem[2]
FROM
  (
    VALUES ('1,2'::TEXT)
  ) AS q(arr),
  LATERAL String_To_Array(q.arr, ',')::INT[] AS elem
;
```

using the implicitly calling `::` operator:

> ERROR: syntax error at or near "::"

One other location at which an explicit `CAST` is required:

```
CREATE INDEX ON ... ( CAST(<straw> AS <gold>) );
```

I doubt there is a syntactical reason, e.g. using extra enclosing parenthesis - which is incorrect here.

Is the explicit function call simply needed at this point as part of the low level implementation? Or does it follow any language rules?

Comment: Interesting observation. I have no idea of what the reason might be, but the same phenomena are discussed in:`https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/10477.1499970459%40sss.pgh.pa.us`

Comment: @Lennart thanks for the link, that seems to be the hiding list topic referred to in one of the linked answers in Erwin's answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Excellent corner case examples. Both of these syntax variants are "explicit type casts", doing exactly the same. It just so happens that some special locations in SQL code only allow functional notation to avoid ambiguities.

As for your second observation:

> One other location at which an explicit `CAST` is required:
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX ON ... ( CAST(<straw> AS <gold>) );
> ```

Shorthand syntax can actually be used here - with an additional set of parentheses to make it unambiguous:

```
CREATE INDEX ON ... ((<straw>::<gold>));
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ee06419a7bc98dfa46c49c8057bd6eb9)*

And either syntax variant matches the other expression in queries, too.
See:

- [Can we create index for key/value of JSONB data type?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/117139/can-we-create-index-for-key-value-of-jsonb-data-type/117161#117161)
- [How to create an index on an integer json property in postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54539/how-to-create-an-index-on-an-integer-json-property-in-postgres/54549#54549)
- [Spliting Datetime into 2 Columns for Restaurant Reservation Schema?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/60905/spliting-datetime-into-2-columns-for-restaurant-reservation-schema/60910#60910)

(There are more efficient ways to do what your first example does, but that's probably beside the point.)

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my *explicit* vs. *implicit* misconception. Indeed I wasn't aware one could simply add parenthesis around an *operator cast* in my second observation; a shame that this PG list topic mentioned in a comment to your first linked answer hasn't turned up - do you happen to have a link handy to explain the need here in detail?

Comment: Oh, and, I *did* use this very example as a suggested, '*maybe more idiomatic*' way to retrieve coordinates from a string column, to then get directly passed into a function in the `SELECT` - see [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380268/93656); if you find that to be a suitable place for an improvement, I'd be happy to stand corrected!

Comment: Nevermind on the link, I just realized @Lennart may have provided it in their comment.

Comment: @geozelot: I was about to suggest `split_part()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8612456/939860. Over [there](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380268/93656), Daniel's answer already suggests as much.

Comment: And after benchmarking that, it seems that is absolutely correct. I do find that rather counter-intuitive, though, but that needs investigation elsewhere. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

It is a bit weird, yes, but the grammar will only accept something syntactically similar to a function call in a function-in-FROM expression.

So that is indeed a trick you can use if you want an arbitrary expression in a `FROM` clause: surround it with an unnecessary `CAST` expression.

PostgreSQL will happily treat anything that looks like a function as a table function in such a context.

Comment: I thought I was sure that this is no syntax issue, and it seems, at this specific location at least, that is true. And I always appreciate to learn some dark trickery; I will explore that some more, just because. Thanks a lot!